# I created a package in react when i installed in another react project the component in package gives error

Tags: reactjs, npm, package

i have created a react component package on npm but when i import the component from package in react app it gives the error in package component.  [error in component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqkqz.png) here's the file on github https://github.com/naveenkash/fluff-tail/tree/master/components/card i tried to import both of the component and it gives error in both of them

```
./node_modules/fluff-tail/components/card/CardHoverInteraction/index.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\navee\Documents\Projects\test2\node_modules\fluff-tail\components\card\CardHoverInteraction\index.js: Unexpected token (7:6)

   5 |   render(){
   6 |     return(
>  7 |       <div className="interaction-card">
     |       ^
   8 |         <div className="content">
   9 |           <h2 className="title">{props.title}</h2>
  10 |           <p className="copy">{props.desc}</p>
```

Comment: to import the package do npm i fluff-tail

Comment: can we see how your trying to import the module?

Comment: it is resolve i just needed to configure babel